# replacing or removing string from href using jquery / javascript

Tags: jquery, replace, href

I am trying to use replace() to remove specific string from hyperlinks on my html pages.  I have come across few posts that showed how to do this and they all are using replace() to achieve this.  It works for IE but in FireFox it's not working.  Here is the code with string that I want to replace (remove).

On my html pages I have links to external websites that are appended by pl script so they can be processed.  I want to remove this script reference from the hyperlink.

Example: `<a href="/cgi-bin/redir.pl?http://www.google.com/" target="_new">Google Search</a>`

I want it to be: `<a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_new">Google Search</a>`

`$("a[href*='/cgi-bin/redir.pl?']").attr('href', function() { 
    return this.replace('/cgi-bin/redir.pl?','');
});`

This code works in IE but it's not working in FireFox.  I have tried many different variation of this code but I was not successful.  I hope someone give me hint on how to make it also work in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$('a[href^="/cgi-bin/redir.pl?"]').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace(/^\/cgi-bin\/redir\.pl\?/, '');

    // or $(this).attr('href', this.href.replace(/^\/cgi-bin\/redir\.pl\?/, ''));
    // or this.href = this.href.substring(18);
});
```